# Keep div faded out after transition

Tags: html, css

I am using a css code to fade in and then fade out an html div, and after a delay, fade in another div. However, after the second div fades in and the code ends, the first div reappears. The code I am using is posted below. I wanted to know how to make sure the first div dosent reappear after the code ends.

```
.text {               
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    35% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    72% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }



.bdy {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we       remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.bdy {
-webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 4.5s;
animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <header>
  <div class="text_paragraph">
   <h1>DEMO</h1>
   <h3>Secondary School</h3>
   <h3>Grade</h3>
  </div>    
  <div class="bdy">
    <h1>hi</h1>      
  </div>        
 </header>
```

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net or a Code Snippet (Ctrl+M) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this ... here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrvob8y6/)

Obs: Add the other css selectors besides -webkit- to make it cross-browser

CSS

```
.text_paragraph {               
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 2s;
    opacity:0;
}

.bdy {
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    35% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    72% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It seems that with the above code, the intro part fades away, but I am unable to add any other element on the space of the intro because the intro is still here, but not visible.